# modifying the size of a map in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I made a map using d3.js with help from code provided in http://www.datavis.fr/index.php?page=map-population , everything works however I am not able to figure out how to resize the map, actually I want to make it bigger but when I tried to modify :

```
var width = 600, height = 550;
```

it didn't work, it only made the scale and the map collide.

width and height also appear in :

```
var projection = d3.geo.conicConformal()
            .center([2.454071, 46.279229])
            .scale(3000)
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

        path.projection(projection);

        var svg = d3.select('#'+id).append("svg")
            .attr("id", "svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("class", "Blues");
```

I'm assuming that's why it doesn't work ? 
Can anyone help me make the map bigger please ?

Thank you

Comment: mock up a fiddle and i will show you

Comment: @thatOneGuy here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4gm10wgq/ , the map is in black because colorbrewer.css is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use :

```
d3.selectAll('svg').attr("transform", "scale(2)");
```

to make it twice bigger or :

```
var projection = d3.geo.conicConformal()
        .center([2.454071, 46.279229])
        .scale(3000)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
        .attr("transform", "scale(2)");
```

Comment: I don't know why but both the methods didn't work, there's no difference in the size

Comment: actually it worked when I modified the scale in : projection = d3.geo.conicConformal()
            .center([2.454071, 46.279229])
            .scale(3000)
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

Answer (score 0):

happened to me too where changing the scale will not take effects,
I looked into my geojson file and found out there was translate and scale values too